# Recycling AngularJS functions

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I am pretty new with AngularJS, but was wondering how to create commonly used functions outside the scope of a controller.

For example, I pretty often need to call a function to start a "Loading" spinner (for RESTful calls, etc).  I tried adding a showLoadingModal() function as a service, but those only seem good for retrieving data from what I've seen.  Do I have to add this function to all of my controllers, or can you create app-level functions somehow?

Comment: Explain "those only seem good for retrieving data". Services are exactly the place where you would define "recycling" functions. Beside that there's a $rootScope on which you can also define methods that will be available throughout the app (if you don't need to access these methods from isolated scopes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define your common method on $rootScope, which will be available via prototypical inheritance to any child scope in your application.

Or, you could certainly define a service called "utilities" and just inject it wherever it's needed.  Services are good for more than wrapping data-retrieval calls!

Of these two approaches, I would recommend the latter.  More testable and less pollution of $rootScope.

Comment: Thanks. I figured a service would be the best, but could not figure out how to even fire an alert() in it. Would you mind giving me an example of how to make a service do this, rather than just returning data? I really appreciate it!

Comment: Ahh!  Angular protects the global "window" context from you when you're inside Angular code like a service implementation.  I think you happened to run into one of the few things you can't "do" the typical way in an Angular service.  To fire alerts, you have to inject Angular's $window service, which encapsulates the browser's window context.  You can then call alerts on it as in $window.alert() . . . this page in the docs explains why they did it this way: http://docs-angularjs-org-dev.appspot.com/api/ng.$window